# Previewing images in the file browser before opening

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, thumbnails

On Windows 7, you can change the view to **Thumbnail** and see what the image is before opening the file. I noticed on Ubuntu that PDF files show a preview, but it seems like `.jpg` files doesn't.

Can this be changed so I can preview the image without opening the file?

Comment: good evening, are you using nautilus? (i guess not) because i just checked it and my 11.10 setup shows thumbnails for jpg images - or did i got the question wrong?

Comment: @spheniscida You are right, displaying thumbnails for .jpg files (and tons of others) is default in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Nautilus (the default Ubuntu install) there is an option to turn off thumbnails. Perhaps you turned it off? Open a file manager and go to **Edit > Preferences > Preview tab > Other previewable files > Show thumbnails: Local Files Only**.

If that doesn't work, you could try clearing the contents of `~/.thumbnails`

Comment: This worked. It was set for `Local Files Only` and changed it to `Always` since the files I was looking at were on the network.

Comment: Same here, I was looking at photos stored on a phone and I needed to changed it to Always so I could see the thumbnail previews, cheers.

Comment: Edit for a progamm in Ubuntu is in the top left corner (next to Activities) and it has the program icon the name and an arrow. Just a addition for new users :)

Comment: Sometimes. And sometimes it's in a sandwich menu. I mean, I love Gnome, but the inconsistency can be annoying since GTK 3.